# Objects releasing on iOS 6 but not in iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, memory-management, ios6

I am having a really weird issue when testing on my 1st gen. iPad (running iOS 5).

I have a UIView that I use as a property (with retain). I nil the property in the parent view's dealloc method. Pretty basic stuff. It works perfect on my iPad 3 running iOS 6, but doesn't get released on my 1st gen.

Any ideas what might be going on?

I'm not using ARC.

Comment: I think in 6 they changed the way views in a NIB get retained.  Is this view in a NIB?

Comment: No, it's not. All my views are programmatic.

Comment: You sure the paren't view's dealloc is being called, I ask because perhaps its a problem w/the parent view.

Comment: I have all my dealloc's logged and the parent view dealloc is being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out. It seems to be a bug in the iOS 6 SDK or maybe I just don't understand it. I have a UIViewController that presents another vc via *presentViewController:animated:completion:* —If I dismiss the presented vc then it releases and subsequently all subviews are removed and all is well.

However, if while the presented vc is showing, I remove/destroy the parent vc, the presented vc is deallocated but, its subviews are not told to removeFromSuperview; This doesn't show up as a leak in instruments, **BUT** it does prevent the subviews from deallocating.

This does not happen on iOS 6, thus I suspect this is a bug in iOS 5. Everything releases/deallocates as one would expect on iOS 6.

If someone has an explanation, or a better understanding of this, I would love to reward the answer to them instead of myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you're retaining it, you have to release it. You can't just nil the instance variable.

So if you're property looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *myView;
```

You're dealloc would either look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [myView release], myView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Or this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self setMyView:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Or this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.myView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

And your property will properly get released--unless something else is retaining it.

Comment: Correction.  You **can** "just nil" the *property* and have it release.  Setting the *instance variable* to nil does not work, though, on either 5 or 6 (unless you're using ARC).

Comment: @HotLicks I always set the property to nil and that works great. I suspect that something else is the matter and I'm currently investigating it. Any ideas?

Comment: @daveMac - There were changes between 5 and 6 regarding how views are linked... dunno the details.  You might be able to gain some insight by putting logs of `retainCount` here and there in your code (with the usual caveat that `retainCount` is officially "meaningless").

Comment: Matt - thanks for clarifying/fixing your answer. I understood how properties work already, but maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

A view controller isn't responsible for removing its view from the superview when the view controller is dealloc'ed.  The view controller is just responsible for releasing its own reference to it.

For example: you can create a view controller, ask for its view, then add that view to another view and throw away the view controller. In that case, you're just using the view controller as a view builder.

I'm not sure why the behavior is different in iOS 6, but would love to know.

Comment: Via api's like presentViewController and then dismissViewController, the view is removed from the superview. Furthermore, the view is clearly not showing anymore. If the parent view controllers view is removed, shouldn't all subviews consequently be removed?

Comment: So, you are removing and destroying the parent VC, what happens to that parent VC's view?  Is it being dealloc'd?

Comment: How would I determine that? Shouldn't it automatically be dealloc'd when you remove and destroy the vc?

Comment: You're only guaranteed that the VC will release it's retain on its view. presentViewController could cause someone to add a retain on the view. Like I was saying earlier - a VC can be used as a view builder, and can then be discarded so long as the view is retained by someone that's still around. I suppose if you really want to track this down, subclass the view and log in its dealloc.

Comment: Which I understand...but, shouldn't whatever is retaining the view in iOS 5 also be retaining the view in iOS 6?

Comment: I'll have to try it out sometime to see what's going on. They do say to always call dismiss if you present. If you present from a presented VC, dismissing the first one dismisses the subsequent ones as well.